# Creating modal with different link

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, modal-dialog

I am trying to create a page with different news articles(each article page directs to a different page that was created). Using modal can I create an environment where the page pop's up in the same window rather than opening in another window? If yes, can someone please help me with the code and example?

Comment: You can use any modal popup. I would suggest you to use jquery ui'modal window:  http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#animated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use jQuery modal dialogs. You can have a link or button for each article and when it gets clicked, open a modal dialog with the article's text.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k9fJn/1/) for a working example.

```
<div class='article' id="article1">
<p>This is article 1, etc...</p>
</div>
<button id='article1Button'>Article 1...</button>

<div class='article' id="article2">
<p>This is another article...</p>
</div>
<button id='article2Button'>Article 2...</button>
```

And the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".article").dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        resizable : false,
        width : 400,
        height: 400,
        modal : true,
        buttons: {
            "Close" : function(){
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close : function(ev, ui) {
            return true;    
        }
    });
$('#article1Button').click(function(){
     $("#article1").dialog("open");
})
$('#article2Button').click(function(){
     $("#article2").dialog("open");
})
});
```

Comment: A small addition to my question.

example: 
<h2 class="colHeading"> <a href="link1.html"> Title Description1 </a> </h2>




<h2 class="colHeading"> <a href="link2.html"> Title Description2 </a> </h2>

based on the above sample code, the content for the popup window will be saved in link1.html or link2.html, when the link is selected I want the content inside either of those pages to appear in the popup window. is this possible?